# Determining the Run Time of a Web Assembly Code

Tags: javascript, c, runtime, emscripten, webassembly

I wanted to compare the runtime of a C code vs its corresponding Web Assembly Code converted using Emscripten. 
Here is the C code

```
int main()
   {
     printf("Hello World");
   }
```

This was then converted to wasm using Emscripten with the following command

```
emcc -o hello.html hello.c
```

I added a few lines to the above C code so as to report the runtime of the C code when it has finished running . Now I want to get the run time of the Web Assembly Code however directly converting this updated C code ignores lots of dynamic Web Assembly instructions being run before that , how to I take them into account .

I googled however was not able to find anything .
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic WebAssembly instructions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to measure, but one way to compare them would be to isolate the code to be run into its own function, and then calling it and measure its run time in `main()` for the native target, and also export the function for the WebAssembly target, where, after you initialized the module, you would measure the run time of the function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tiny-wasm-runtime (which I wrote), you can see an example of how to measure the function execution time here:
https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime/blob/main/examples/tests/index.html

You can also measure the time directly inside the C function using something like this:

```
 #include <time.h>
 time_t start, end;
 time(&start);
 printf("hello world");
 time(&end);
 twr_conlog("%d ms",end-start);
```

anthony
https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime